# Right padding when title breaks in not very wide container

Tags: css, padding

How would you guys [approach this](http://jsfiddle.net/BGxmQ/) in the best semantic way possible?

I have a background for the title (inline) which is padded on margins but when the title breaks to the next row it loses the padding on the first row, on the right side.

Comment: Also, the padding is gone on the second line on the left. This seems correct to me, since the padding is on the h2 element as a whole, and not on the **individual words** of the element.

Answer (score 0):

Make the `<h2>` an **inline-block**:

```
display: inline-block;
```

That will make it a block that's inline with the text.

Comment: that doesn't help at all, the background needs to stay with the text, if the first row is longer than the second, the background on it should reflect that